# Kafka vm.max_map_count

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a Kafka cluster for Kafka stream application.

After some hours our broker went down and we got `OutOfMemory` exception.

We saw the `vm.max_map_count` is not enough and maps memory of the process is above 40K.

Can someone explain what can be the problem or what influence on that parameter?

The number always increases and never goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the pull request at https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/4358/files (both the change being proposed and the comments reacting to it), it appears that each log segment (i.e. file) in each partition on each topic on the broker consumes two maps.

I would expect the value to rise until you reach a steady-state where all topics have logs that are old enough to start being deleted due to the retention interval. At that point, each new file would be expected to occur at around the same time as an older one is deleted (assuming roughly constant message rates). I would expect the value to drop if topics were deleted or if you changed the configuration of an existing topic or the full broker (e.g. reduce the log retention time or cause the logs to roll over less frequently), and to go up if you change the configuration in the opposite direction.