# Kafka brokers crashing at random interval

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jvm

We are running Kafka brokers in containers with ECS service of AWS. The cluster is of 3 brokers. We have encountered an issue where any of the brokers would randomly crash with a Java fatal error as below.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fef4a3baf9e, pid=1, tid=0x00007feb7feb7700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 9297 C2 org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileLogInputStream$FileChannelRecordBatch.compressionType()Lorg/apache/kafka/common/record/CompressionType; (10 bytes) @ 0x00007fef4a3baf9e [0x00007fef4a3b9f80+0x101e]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://www.azulsystems.com/support/
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/B3B0569k), [here](https://pastebin.com/PdWNUJSu) and [here](https://pastebin.com/MYVSLzV9) is the entire crash dump of hs_err_pid1.log. Divided the dump into three parts due to Pastebin limit.

Can anyone please help me to identify the problem here.

Comment: Hard to fire issue :) However, Did you looking for log in dmesg ( docker host ) and looking for ``` OutOfMemory ``` ? may be you need to setting ```vm.max_map_count``` in-crease/ change your instance size ? - [Kafka performance tuning](https://rahulsinghai.blogspot.com/2018/01/kafka-performance-tuning.html). - [Kafka Out of memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754162/kafka-vm-max-map-count) ? - [Virtual memory tuning for ElasticSearch Context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can search the log in dmesg ( docker host ) and look for `OutOfMemory` ?  may be you need to setting `vm.max_map_count` in-crease/ change your instance size ?

- [Kafka performance tuning](https://rahulsinghai.blogspot.com/2018/01/kafka-performance-tuning.html).
- [Kafka Out of memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754162/kafka-vm-max-map-count) ?
- [Virtual memory tuning for ElasticSearch Context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html)